# HTML text not showing in footer over background

Tags: html, css, text, background, footer

```
 <footer>

        <h4>Engman Online Photorgraphy Institure
        is where learning happens </h4>
        
            <p>Copyright &copy;2023 Engman Online Photography Institute
                All Rights Reserved </p>
```

and i did this in css

```
.footer{
background-size: cover;
    background-color:rgb(88, 90, 83);
    height: 450px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 40%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

and text is not showing or bacground not showing ...
ether way i cant put this togther ..

can someone help me and tell me how to do my footer Please so much ..i am trying this second day and is not working ...

i also did this

```
<div class="footer1">
    

        <h4 span class="text-of-footer-main">Engman Online Photorgraphy Institure </span>
    <span class="text-of-footer-sub">is where learning happens </h4></span>

    <p>Copyright &copy;2023 Engman Online Photography Institute
        All Rights Reserved </p>
```

```
.footer1{
  
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:rgb(88, 90, 83);
    height: 450px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 40%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  color: aliceblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

NOT WORKING ETHER ...please someone help me
thanks so much

i would like to do my footer..text on top of this gray pentagonal bacground ..that all ..
it should be simple but is not working for me ..PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

You only shared with us your `footer` CSS rules but you need to define some rules for the `h4` and `p` tags inside the footer.

```css
footer{
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:rgb(88, 90, 83);
  height: 450px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%,100% 40%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  color: aliceblue;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer h4,
footer p{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}

footer h4{
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<h4>Engman Online Photorgraphy Institure is where learning happens</h4>

<p>Copyright &copy;2023 Engman Online Photography Institute All Rights Reserved </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: O MY! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! YOU GENIUS !!! ..I just started to learn 3 weeks ago and am not sure what I am doing thank you so much, so much!You are amazing! Thank you again. You save me . I did try so many things but could not figure it out ..A well.now I know . Thank You again, and all the best for YOU !

Comment: @m.najder I'm glad I helped you. Please accept my answer as a solution (by clicking on the tick next to the answer).